# Передача агумента var из <c:forEach> в адресную строку

Tags: java, jsp

Опыта работы с JSP мало, поэтому прошу совета, как лучше поступить.

Имеется форма, где пользователь выбирает доступную конфигурацию, и отправляет её на сервер.

```
<form action="/configuration/${configuration.key}" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Configuration name:</label></td>
            <td>
                <label>
                    <select name="configuration">
                        <c:forEach var="configuration" items="${configurations}">
                            <option value="${configuration.key}">${configuration.value}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Send" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

При отправке, в адресной строке, на месте, где ${configuration.key} пусто. Как правильно передать значение из блока forEach в адресную строку, и есть ли такая возможность?

Comment: form action="/configuration/${configuration.key} должно быть внутри forEach

Comment: Тогда будут создаваться на странице такое же кол-во форм/кнопок, сколько и элементов в цикле. Это не есть хорошо

Comment: А по идее, я же могу отправить целый объект и в контроллере достать у него id?